# MySQL - select column with values and create 'virtual column'

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have 3 tables.

tb_employees:

```
+---------------+---------------+
|  id_employee  |   employee    |
+---------------+---------------+
|     1         | Robert Tomson |
|     2         | Jhonatan Weg  |
|     3         |   Eva Uhte    |
+---------------+---------------+
```

tb_requirements:

```
+---------------+-----------------+
|  id_requirem  |    requirem     |
+---------------+-----------------+
|     11        |      Photo      |
|     12        | Criminal Record |
|     13        |  Shooting Test  |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

tb_details:

```
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
|  id_details   |  id_employee    |  id_requirem  |
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
|     21        |       1         |       11      |
|     22        |       1         |       12      |
|     23        |       1         |       13      |
|     24        |       2         |       12      |
|     25        |       2         |       13      |
|     26        |       3         |       11      |
|     27        |       3         |       13      |
+---------------+-----------------+---------------+
```

What I have to do is a `SELECT` of `requirem` (the description) and an specific employee (for exm. `WHERE id_employee = '2'`) and ADD a 'virtual column' that shows if the employee has that requirement or not.

Like This: `WHERE id_employee = '2'`

```
+----------------+-----------------+
|    requirem    | virtual_column  |
+----------------+-----------------+
|     Photo      |       0         |
|Criminal Record |       1         |
| Shooting Test  |       1         |
+---------------+------------------+
```

`WHERE id_employee = '3'`

```
+----------------+-----------------+
|    requirem    | virtual_column  |
+----------------+-----------------+
|     Photo      |       1         |
|Criminal Record |       0         |
| Shooting Test  |       1         |
+---------------+------------------+
```

Where 0 = Employee doesn't have that requirement, 1 = Employee has that requirement : from the tb_detail.

I really don't have an idea how to do this.

Can u help me please?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: What kind of job *requires* a criminal record and a shooting test? Mafia hitman?

Comment: Hahaha, it was just a test to understand the 'sql logic' :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to achieving your goal is an `OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT r.requirem, (d.id_requirem IS NOT NULL) virtual_column
  FROM tb_requirements r LEFT JOIN tb_details d
    ON r.id_requirem = d.id_requirem
   AND d.id_employee = 2
```

Output for `id_employee = 2`:

```
|        REQUIREM | VIRTUAL_COLUMN |
|-----------------|----------------|
|           Photo |              0 |
| Criminal Record |              1 |
|   Shooting Test |              1 |
```

Output for `id_employee = 3`:

```
|        REQUIREM | VIRTUAL_COLUMN |
|-----------------|----------------|
|           Photo |              1 |
| Criminal Record |              0 |
|   Shooting Test |              1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ca6b/3)** demo

Further reading:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)